# Vertical Bar for "Integral evaluated at" breaks

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to include the vertical bar for showing an integral evaluated at from 0.5 to 1, but the bar keeps breaking, is there a simpler way to write it? I can't use the physics package because I'm doing this in Notion. Any help would be appreciated!

```
b_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_0^T f(x)\sin (\frac{2\pi nx}{T}) dx \\
b_n = 2\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(2\pi nx)dx \\
= 2\left(\int_0^{0.5} f(x) \sin(2\pi nx)dx + \int_{0.5}^{1} f(x) \sin(2\pi nx)dx\right) \\
= 2\left( \int_0^{0.5} \sin(2\pi nx)dx - \int_{0.5}^{1} \sin(2\pi nx)dx\right) \\
= 2 \left( \left( \left( \frac{-\cos(2\pi nx)}{2\pi n x} \right)\biggr\vert_{0}^{0.5} \right) - \left( \left( \frac{-\cos(2\pi nx)}{2\pi n x} \right)\biggr\vert_{0.5}^{1}    \right) \right)
```

[image: Problem seen in the last line of the equation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  When I take a wild guess and enclose your code in `\documentclass{amsart} \begin{document} \begin{gather*} ... \end{gather*} \end{document}`, then the bar is fine.  So something else you've not shown us is the problem.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was, because I didn't change the code and now that problem is just not there anymore and it looks normal. Thanks for the help!